# MetroFramework MetroTabControl Alignment:Left(Right) Bug?

Tags: c#

Использую MetroFramework.dll. Необходимо сделать вертикальный MetroTabControl. Когда меняю свойство Alignment на Left(Right) не отображается название первой вкладки, т.е. сама вкладка есть, но текста названия не видно, в чём может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Товарищ, вы среди своих. Можете общаться на родном языке.

Comment: @VladD: а вы ничего не перепутали в восьмом слове?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Тьфу. И правда. Имелось в виду in Russian, конечно.